# How do I gain access to Perception training as a Hexblade MC Rogue in early Heroic?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, optimization

I am currently about to start playing as a 1st level fey-pact Hexblade stiker and I'm acting as the rogue (traps, locks, and so on) in a small party. I am currently planning to take the multi-class 'Sneak of Shadows' rogue feat at level one and I have used it to help cover all the major abilities, apart from my perception, which is still an abysmal 1.

Could anyone make any suggestions as to how best to boost this vital rogue stat? Could anyone tell me if taking the Multi-class feat at level 1 and then a perception training feat at level 2 the best value I can get? The reason I took the multi-class feat is because I was hoping to add sneak-attack damage to my Hexblade attacks, encounter powers and dailies to help take down big foes quickly, will this work?

*Edit*

What I mean by acting the rogue is that my character has training in Thievery (from the feat), Stealth, Bluff, and Intimidate and is the go-to guy for those skills in the party. His weak area is that while he can disarm traps he has little chance of spotting them or finding secret doors, etc. Unfortunately I can't alter my base stats or my background to compensate. Would I be able to stack a theme on top of a background and would it interfere with my other skills?

*Edit 2*

Thanks guys, that's all really solid advice, I'll defiantly talk to the DM abut thievery instead of perception but they won't budge on minor changes to class fluff so I don't rate my chances. Still, I'm really happy with my class at the moment and want to keep it, so maybe I'll just keep a friend with me until level 2 (don't want to stretch my luck further than that because that's two people to fail a stealth check instead of one). Unfortunately I really need the Bad Sign background due to how few healing surges I get (that will be feat three). It's just a pity the multiclass feat doesn't train stealth too (are there any more of those I could stack for better abilities, or a feat that give bonuses to several abilities?).

Comment: When you say "acting as the rogue" what do you mean by that? Perhaps you should come and join us in the chat room so we can delve into this a bit more. For now, this [question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/11575/how-do-i-represent-a-warlock-with-a-background-in-thievery?rq=1) may have some answers for you.

Comment: Is your background taken at this point? That's the best way to get access to train perception without giving anything up. The next best option is to rely on another party member for finding traps

Comment: To be honest, what's the purpose of going Hex if you really need the rogue skills? Wouldn't the other way around be slightly better?

Comment: Here's another question for you - does there have to be a rogue in the party? Will the group be prevented from achieving its goals unless you can hide or disarm traps?

Comment: This is turning into a conversation that would be more appropriate and effective in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your character there are 2 ways to access Perception training, and I'm not sure either of them is a good idea, so I'll provide two alternative suggestions.

First the ways to access it:

1. Access the training through a background. There are numerous backgrounds that add perception as a class skill, allowing you to train it that way. This is good, but I believe in your case your background is already spoken for (you'll need to evaluate the tradeoff between more HP and gaining training to perception).
2. Access it through perception training as a feat. This gives it to you at the cost of a feat, which is OK, but since you're already multi-classing it means waiting until L2 which might be too late (if a trap splats you at L1 all the planning is moot, this is unlikely, but would be hilarious in a really horrible sort of way).

Now, for some recommendations.

1. Without changing your class, your best bet for now is to get another party member to train perception (perhaps one who is stronger in WIS). They will likely be your scouting buddy so they should have at least a modest DEX investment and be trained in stealth (so preferably not your Paladin friend in full plate and a heavy shield). This is your best option.
2. This option involves changing your character concept. If this were me, you seem *very* concerned about making sure the roguish skills are covered, that seems like a good reason to be a rogue primary and a Hexblade MC. This probably changes the flavor you're going for, but it might best serve the party if you don't have a ready scouting buddy option.

This final option is to ask your DM to let you spot traps with thievery. This is actually what we do in our main group (due to an initial misunderstanding of the rules, and no will to change what we've been doing). It makes slightly more sense from the rogue's perspective (how many rogues have a decent WIS score?) and doesn't really imbalance anything. It might be something to talk to your DM about if you're on good terms with him.

Comment: The DM says "We'll work something out" which is kinda code for "we messed up the balance but that's 0k because suddenly all the traps are signposted" XD Thanks anyway guys, I think we'll be 0k.